# Was DJ the hacker they were looking for?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

DJ didn't have the rose broach thing that Maz said he'd have, but I had the feeling that nevertheless he was the person they'd been sent to find and maybe the guy they saw with the broach had either stolen, won and bought the broach from DJ who was clearly in some kind of desperate situation (i.e. in jail and presumably broke). And Maz had said there was only one person (she knew of) that could break them on to the First Order's ship and DJ did actually do that...

Is there any evidence to support DJ being the person they were looking for? Or was it just sheer luck that they happened to find the only *other person* that could break them in that Maz didn't know about?